# XSLT2.0 Uppercase first Letter of Regex Match

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0

I have a a use case to convert camelCase elements in an xml document to NewCase as shown:

Current:

```
<firstName>John</firstName>
<lastName>Smith</lastName>
<userId>5692</userId>
```

Desired:

```
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<UserId>5692</UserId>
```

I must facilitate this through XSLT. In order to do this, I identified a regex that would capture the camelCase for my requirement:

```
\b([a-z])([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*)\b
```

From there, I have been attempting to do this via XSLT2.0 by using the replace function:

```
 replace($xmlToParse,"\b([a-z])([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*)\b","REPLACED")
```

For the final block, I want to take the first segment of the matched regex (in lowerCase the segments would be 'l' and 'owercase' based on the above regex), and use the upper-case function to change that first segment/letter to upper case (so lowerCase would be LowerCase), and do this for every regex match in the XML. Unfortunately thus far I have been unable to achieve it.

Would anyone be able to give any insight on how to link it all together?

Comment: Almost got there using XPath --

replace(/,"([a-z])([a-z]*[A-Z][a-z]*)", "$1")

Going to reopen it as an XPath question.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "*[matches(name(), '[a-z]+[A-Z][a-z]*')]">
  <xsl:element name=
   "{upper-case(substring(name(),1,1))}{substring(name(),2)}">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped into a single top element to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <firstName>John</firstName>
    <lastName>Smith</lastName>
    <userId>5692</userId>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
      <UserId>5692</UserId>
</t>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Greatly appreciated.